# Find log files under multiple directories and compress each file with its own name and date

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compression, logging, tar

I have multiple directories like below and I want to compress each file in place.

```
/var/dir1/logs/logfile.log
/var/dir2/logs/logfile.log
/var/dir3/logs/logfile.log
```

I want to use `find` and `tar` with combine but I don't know how to use the file name and path as variables.

This command zips all files in the one file:

```
find /dir/to/search/ -name "*.log" -exec tar -rvf out.tar {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `xargs`.

```bash
find *.log | xargs -I input zip input.zip input
```

Note that this is the Mac version of xargs. The behaviour might be different on Ubuntu, but hopefully something close to this should work.

`xargs` works by taking each line of the input (via stdin) and running some command for it. The `-I input` means that for each line, the input line is used instead of the string `input`. So in this case, it runs the `zip` command on each file.

Comment: Thank you @Simon Lundberg. xargs worked!